# determining the limiting behavior of a function defined by a Fourier transform

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I need to determine this limit value

$$ \lim_{r\rightarrow 0 }  \frac{\partial}{\partial r }\left\{ r \sum_{\mathbb{k} } e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} } [k^2 +1 - k (k^2 + 2 )^{1/2}] 
 \right \}  .$$

Essentially, I have a function $f(\vec{r})$ defined by the Fourier transform

$$ f(\vec{r}) = f(r) = \sum_{\mathbb{k} } e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} } [k^2 +1 - k (k^2 + 2 )^{1/2}]  . $$

The problem is to determine its behavior near the origin $\vec{r}=0 $. Here the sum is over a 3-dim lattice, i.e., $\vec{k}= (2\pi/L)(m,n,l)$ with $m,n,l$ being integers from $-\infty $ to $+\infty $.

It is expected that

$$f(r) = \frac{A}{r} + B + \text{higher oders of } r .$$

The problem is to determine $B$, which is a subleading term.